# Discrete Derivative with more than one delta x

Tags: calculus, discrete-calculus

I have a weird representation for a discrete derivative problem.
Say we have:

$$Δ M(x) = f(x) Δx$$

This means that we can rewrite it as $\frac{∂M(x)}{∂x} = f(x)$. However, the problem I face looks like this:

$$Δ M(x) = f(x) Δx + g(x) Δx^2$$

Thus,  $$\frac{∂M(x)}{∂x} = f(x) + g(x) Δx$$

Can I also say that:
$$\frac{∂^2M(x)}{∂x^2} = \frac{∂f(x)}{∂x}  + g(x)$$

Or is this unacceptable? If not, then how do I get rid of the $Δx$ to move the problem from discrete to continuous?

Comment: Yes, you can (under a certain conditions, e.g. $M$ is second differential, $f$ is differential, $g$ is continuous, etc).

Comment: @Leon But in doing so I assume that $ \frac{∂ f(x) }{∂ x}=   lim(\frac{f(x) }{Δ x}) $ and as I understand it should be  $ \frac{∂ f(x) }{∂ x}= lim( \frac{Δ f(x) }{Δ x} )$ 
Is that valid?

Comment: is there any mistake in the first equation in your comment, missing $\Delta$? Anyway I am not sure when working with $\Delta$-notation. Anyway, if you are an engineer, all you said are correct! If you are a mathematics student, be careful, you should work with $\Delta$ only when you understand it clearly!